# new user account creation controlled by admin in HSQLDB

Tags: java, database, admin, hsqldb

I use a HSQLDB(Remote Server) ; need create Admin with priviliges controls the creation of any other new user account (the new user fill the new user's form, persisted in DB,but account not active till admin approves it)

admins & new users each in different table...but both tables in same schema.

admins gets all new acount's requests ..shows as GUI table to the admin..and upon a click of a button, the account gets activated.
is this possible ? or is there better easier way...

P.S :The HSQLDB v2.4 manuals (chapter 6) kind of ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I found a way to do that...for a small or medium database .

when a new user fill the "new user form" , the form gets persisted in the "new users account" table which consist of a column named "approval_col" with default value string "not_approved" ,

in the user login process, an if() statement checks the "approval_col" value , if "not_approved" then user gets a massage to wait for approval....otherwise the new user enters to the program.

on the admin side , as he gets all the new accounts requests through a gui table taken infos from the "new users accounts" table...then he changes the value of "approval_col" of a specific request to "approved" through an UPDATE statement.

No need for change buttton...can change the value of the column cell with the col.setCellValue() which calls the UPDATE statement.